# How to resolve "svn: Can't find a temporary directory: Internal error"?

Tags: svn

I have already googled the message, and I have plenty of disk space available on the SVN server (it's about 4% usage of 150 GB).

I have noticed that when I try `echo $TMPDIR` at the command prompt on the SVN server I get nothing.

What is making this a little confusing is that I only get this message from one location when I do an `svn diff` (that I've tested so far) - this error is not coming up when I try from three other computers (one of which is testing against the exact same repository, the other two are different repositories on the same svn server).

About the only difference I can see is that the broken working copy is connecting to the server by an IP address where all the others are using a server name (although this resolves over DNS to the same IP Address).

I'm hoping that I don't have to scratch the broken working copy and checkout a new one - unfortunately, this is a legacy project and not all changes have been properly revisioned.

Comment: Can you please add the OS and the version for both client and servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually figured a method to do this (as well as getting everything currently unrevisioned under proper version control):

1. Use the "find" command to strip all of the .svn directories from the broken working copy
2. Move the working copy to another location
3. Checkout a new working copy into the original location
4. Recursively copy the old/stripped working copy into the new one
5. No more problem

I reckon there must have been some corruption in one of the .svn files for that working copy.

Answer (score 4):

You also get this error if  the **disk is full**, I discovered.

Free up some space and the error disappears.

Comment: You also get this error if the server disk is full

Comment: I was going insane because my local machine had plenty of space... and then realized it was the SERVER that was out of space. Good times.

Answer (score 0):

On the computer with the problem, try deleting manually that directory, do not commit, but update your svn in your local machine, redo the changes on that directory, it is one directory.  That usually works with me on similar errors.

Comment: It's the entire working copy - and as I said in my original post, there's a lot of unrevisioned stuff in there (which is a problem in itself that needs to be resolved, but that's for another day) so deleting the directory and updating is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by running the script provided here:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn-clean